# if-statement with Parameter Query

Tags: ms-access

Please provide me with the SQL to copy and paste in order to have my if-statement prompt the user to input the `want_date`, but if the user just clicks "OK", then the default value will be the current date.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input ( want_date )
SELECT [please input want date or just click ok to use todays current date] AS Expr1;
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nz([Input Date],now())`

`nz` is a function the returns the second item if the first is null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more into MS SQL , not sure if same syntax will work on access. but can give it a try or get an idea. if value is null, it will use the current date from system.

INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input (ISNULL(@Want_date,getdate())

Comment: I tried aplying your code, but it gives me a syntax error. Please advise